# Custom console using enhancedlist and detail tag

Tags: visualforce-component, jquery

I was trying to build a custom console i.e., list views with details of record below the list view.

I was trying to make use of  and  tag for that and i do have half baked code where i need to modify the javascript but i am facing issues while using enahncedlist and detail tag together i.e., list views are not loading.

would someone be so kind as to check my code and suggest some viable work around?

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Contact">
 <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
 <script>
        $vfjq = jQuery.noConflict();
        $vfjq(document).ready(function() {
            $vfjq('a').click(function (event) 
            {
              event.preventDefault(); 
              $('#contactdetail').load('ajax/newcontent.html'); 
            });
        });    
 </script>
 <apex:variable var="contactId" value="testrecordId"/>
 <apex:enhancedList height="400" type="Contact" />
 <apex:outputPanel id="contactdetail" >
        <apex:detail subject="{!contactId}" relatedList="true" relatedListHover="true" showChatter="false" />
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to have it as enhanced list or will Iframe do

Bad part is that you need to hard code the list view Id: 
with istdp if you do not want to strip the header and sidebar info(not recommended)

```
    <apex:page tabStyle="Contact">  
    <apex:iframe src="/003?fcf=00Bd0000003jFUd&isdtp=vw"/>
 <apex:variable var="contactId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"/>
     <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:detail subject="{!contactId}" relatedList="true" relatedListHover="true" showChatter="false" />
     </apex:outputPanel>    
     </apex:page>
```

With no istdp params

```
 <apex:page tabStyle="Contact" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">   
    <apex:iframe src="/003?fcf=00Bd0000003jFUd"/>
 <apex:variable var="contactId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"/>
     <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:detail subject="{!contactId}" relatedList="true" relatedListHover="true" showChatter="false" />
     </apex:outputPanel>

     </apex:page>
```

Comment: great idea... but when i want to show record detail page below the list view when user clicks on record name. I am not sure whether we can do this using jQery or not?

Comment: There are 2 problems 1) my minimal knowledge with jquery 2) you are trying to work on 2 different domains (na14./na13.) and vf pages sit on c.na14 /c.na13 domains so accessing an iframe from a different domnain is very very hard and needs an expert to look at this. @sfdcfox can you help us tackle this

Answer (score 2):

I hardly managed to hack . Here is the complete code with jquey.
  enhancedlist and detail are still not working....but we can code view part and rerender as of now i am using iframe.

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Contact" sidebar="false" controller="contactconsole">
 <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
 <script>
        $vfjq = jQuery.noConflict();
        $vfjq(document).ready(function() {
           document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
                var myparent = $vfjq(event.target).parent();
                if(myparent.is('a'))
                {
                    var href_sel = myparent.prop('href');
                    var lastFifteen = href_sel.substr(href_sel.length - 15);
                    if(lastFifteen.indexOf("003") == 0)
                    {
                         event.stopPropagation();
                         event.preventDefault();
                         rerenderdetail(lastFifteen);
                    }
                }            
            }, true);
        });    
 </script>
 <apex:enhancedList height="400" type="Contact" />
 <apex:form >
 <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderdetail" reRender="contactdetail">
     <apex:param name="contactId" value="contactId" assignTo="{!contactId}"/>
 </apex:actionfunction>

 <apex:outputPanel id="contactdetail" >
            <!--<apex:detail subject="{!contactId}" relatedList="true" inlineEdit="true"  relatedListHover="true" showChatter="false" />-->
            <apex:iframe src="/{!contactId}"/>
 </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:form>
```